# jax-rs (jersey) cannot see REMOTE_USER header in javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, tomcat, authorization, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using jax-rs (jersey) to create a website / web-service that other users can access, and I have come to the point where adding authentication / authorization is a necessity; so that I can use the security annotations, I have implemented a `javax.servlet.Filter` whose url-pattern is `*/`.

Apache is running in front of my tomcat instance, verifying credentials and passing the `REMOTE_USER` header to my web-service so I can determine what resources a user has access to. My problem is that regardless of what request object I look at, I see no `REMOTE_USER` header; I've also tried injecting the Request with the `@Context` param, but to no avail.

Please help me.

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app ...>
<display-name>ws</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>REST Service</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>base.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/views</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(js|css|(WEB-INF/views))/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>auth-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>base.auth.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>auth-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>REST Service</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**filter.java:**

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;      
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    AuthUser userPrincipal = null;
    Object sessionUser = session.getAttribute("user");
    if(sessionUser != null) userPrincipal = (AuthUser) sessionUser;
    else userPrincipal = new AuthUser();

    // load in the user principal
    Enumeration eheaders = req.getAttributeNames();
    while(eheaders.hasMoreElements()){
        System.out.println(eheaders.nextElement().toString());
    }

    String user = (String) req.getAttribute("REMOTE_USER");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest.getAttribute()` and `getAttributeNames()` has nothing to do with HTTP headers. Try `getHeaderNames()` and `getHeaders()`

Also instead of adding a servlet filter, you may consider adding a Jersey filter - see http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/package-summary.html

Comment: Martin, I'll give your answer a try; Can you give me some context as to why a Jersey filter is better? I also cannot figure out how to wire it in so I can use the security annotations; I understand about the factory init param, but how does Jersey find my filter/security context object?

Comment: Jersey filter is better because it is applied to all calls that land in Jersey servlet/filter - i.e. you don't have to manually ensure your auth filter and your Jersey filter both use the same URI mapping. Also in Jersey filter you can inject some additional info Jersey provides that can be useful (e.g. UriInfo or HttpHeaders), you can set your own SecurityContext, etc. Not sure what you mean by factory init param. Jersey finds your filter because you have to put the name of the filer class into the Jersey filter init params as written on that page I linked.